# Google Apps Script - Exception: Page element is not of type shape

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides-api

I store in a Google Sheets table some data about quotes, which I inject in a Google Slides (duplicate of a template).

[image]

My script works replacing the placeholders with the cell content and injecting the images from the URLs. However, I get an error message that breaks the rest of the script.

```
function createSlide_(currentAppName) {
  let presentation = SlidesApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/###/edit');
  let templateSlide = presentation.getSlideById('###');
  let newSlide = templateSlide.duplicate();
  newSlide.setSkipped(false);

  newSlide.replaceAllText('{{AppName}}',currentAppName[0]);
  newSlide.replaceAllText('{{Company}}',currentAppName[1]);
  newSlide.replaceAllText('{{Founder}}',currentAppName[2]);
  newSlide.replaceAllText('{{Designation}}',currentAppName[3]);
  newSlide.replaceAllText('{{quote}}',currentAppName[4]);

  newSlide.getShapes().forEach(s => {
    if (s.getText().asString().trim() == "{{AppImage}}") s.replaceWithImage(DriveApp.getFileById(currentAppName[5].match(/[-\w]{25,}/)).getBlob());
    if (s.getText().asString().trim() == "{{FounderImage}}") s.replaceWithImage(DriveApp.getFileById(currentAppName[6].match(/[-\w]{25,}/)).getBlob());
    });
};
```

**Exception: Page element is not of type shape.**

- I also tried to store `var shapes = newSlide.getShapes()`, check that it exists and then iterate if `typeof shapes !== 'undefined'` and `shapes.length > 0`.
- I also tried the `getPageElements` method - the script does not work.

Any idea please?

Comment: Please share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output. Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Not know exactly what is failing in you script I created a simple example.  Try this and see what you template consists of.  I have a simple slide with just one text box.

```
function test() {
  try {
    let presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
    let slides = presentation.getSlides();
    slides.forEach( slide => console.log(slide.getObjectId()) );
    let template = presentation.getSlideById("p");
    let slide = template.duplicate();
    slide.replaceAllText("{{hello}}","goodbye");
    let elements = slide.getPageElements();
    elements.forEach( element => console.log(element.getPageElementType().toString()))
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

Execution log

```
3:52:46 PM  Notice  Execution started
3:52:47 PM  Info    p
3:52:47 PM  Info    SHAPE
3:52:47 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: Thank you TheWizEd - I updated the code according to your advice and now its works… I've defined elements to get their types, the logs were ok and… the code went like a star! Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you mean to say "now it works"?